# Java/libgdx - player.getx() and player.gety()

Tags: java, pointers, exception, null, libgdx

I have a very simple program that has enemies follow the player, who can freely move about the x and y axis. The problem is, every time I try to do something like `player.getx()` or `player.gety()`, it returns with a Null pointer exception. Found another person with this problem, but it didn't fix mine. Here's what I got:

```
public class SpaceObject {

public float x;
public float y;
protected float x2;
protected float y2;

public float getx() { return x; }
public float gety() { return y; }
}

//Here's my camera attempting to access player.getx() and player.gety(),  returning with a null pointer exception:

    camera.position.set(player.getx(), player.gety(), 0);



// Here's an example of a bullet-enemy detection(I'm trying to perform enemy1.getx() and enemy1.gety(), also gives me a Null pointer exception):

//bullet-smallenemy1 collision
    for(int i = 0; i < bullet1.size(); i++){
        Bullet1 b = bullet1.get(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < smallenemy1.size(); j++){
            SmallEnemy1 s = smallenemy1.get(j);
            if(s.contains(b.getx(), b.gety())){ 
                bullet1.remove(i);
                i--;
                smallenemy1.remove(j);
                j--;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

I have everything pasted below, just in case the above doesn't help. I know there's a lot of clutter. All I need fixed is the Null pointer exception.

http://pastebin.com/3CqkNTgd

Comment: This has nothing to do with libgdx. Just a programming error. "player" is never initialised in "theGame". It is null.

Comment: You can treat everything that was not instantiated or initialized as a default object with working methods.                                                                       However, I had already solved this problem. I was very noobish at the time, I had forgotten to write the methods.

Answer (score 0):

NullpointerException means that player is not instantiated at all, or set to null. 
It seems you never call the init() method.